# Keep same address for Mobile Page

Tags: http-headers, user-agent

How can I keep the same address (I mean, example.com/products/product-name) on desktop and mobile browsers and make different versions of page for both?

You can see an example on this site: http://netshoes.com.br/
There's no mobile version explicited (like netshoes.com.br/mobile) but all pages are the same and I found a Javascript code that gives the "mobile" and "desktop" values to configure the page:

```
dataLayerGA = [{
    'site': {
    'name': 'Netshoes',
    'domain': 'www.netshoes.com.br',
    'country': 'BR',
    'application': 'desktop'
  }
                      
}];
```

When Loaded in mobile, the 'application': turns 'mobile';

How can I do that?

Comment: Responsive design. or detecting mobile device using browser signature? Something like that will achieve it. However lean towards responsive-fluid design.

Comment: [Responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)

Answer (score 2):

The company site you linked to is using **[user-agent sniffing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)**. It's a technique which tries to detect the device being used and serves up different CSS/JS appropriate to that device.

**I wouldn't recommend using this technique.** [Nor does CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/). It's highly unlikely to be forwards compatible (to not be able to work on newer devices) and is unreliable with current devices.

**Instead, make your content available for both devices and using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) change the look and feel of the site.**
I also recommend JS libraries like [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) to give JS similar abilities to media queries.

Comment: Media queries also have a down side when compared to serving content based on the client, they bloat your markup. You end up serving content to a client that will never be used by it. (i.e  full browser CSS to a mobile client) So I would suggest it's not quite as black and white as you imply.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll take a look;
But how could this great e-commerce company use a not recommended technique? It's the greatest on Brazil and on my thinking, they use all of the best.

Comment: @Liam How do media queries bloat markup (CSS isn't markup)? With the sites I've worked on, the size difference for CSS files for desktop/mobile is negligible, especially when compressed. I don't feel I claim to a black and white solution, instead I recommend an approach which is used the world over.

Comment: @BrunoMosciattiG.Maciel The greatest companies don't make the best digital choices. Browser sniffing is (personally) not a good solution, and I feel it is inherently flawed. See also, [browser detection is bad](https://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/)

Comment: @evolutionxbox and NetShoes is really using "browser sniffing"?

Comment: I tested it in Chrome 42 and the site doesn't respond to resolution changes. It did however change when I switched the user agent string.

Comment: @evolutionxbox ok. So, Is there another way to do this? I mean, only one page for both versions (desktop and mobile) - I'm not talking about Responsive, i'm talking of a MOBILE version in the same page that the DESKTOP version.

Comment: What's the difference between a desktop and mobile version? Resolution? How come my mobile tablet has a resolution of over 1080p? Is that a desktop experience? What content would you hide on mobile that you'd want on desktop? If you are willing to hide it, why have it there at all? **Responsive design is a tool** which when used well can achieve more than a "desktop/mobile" variant website.

Comment: as I told, my site is full Responsive, it's all ok about Responsive. But, I want a mobile version with different contents.

Comment: Personally I think you're going about it backwards, but I do understand that sometimes you need to have differing content on a mobile than on desktop. Either you can use user agent sniffing (on a server or client-side) to serve different content, or you can use something like, [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) and edit the HTML after the site has loaded.